# Arabic Text is not Printing in Intermec PB51 Printer Using LinePrinter Code

Tags: android

I am using the Intermec PB51 printer. Using the same code but it's not printing Arabic text in the correct way. It's differentiating the Arabic text characters. Can anyone help me to print Arabic Text in Intermec PB51 with LinePrinter Code?

```
Arabic864 arabic864 = new Arabic864();
byte[] arabicTXT = arabic864.Convert("بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم", false);
mLinePrinter.write(arabicTXT);
mLinePrinter.newLine(1);

mLinePrinter.writeLine("Intermec Printer Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

You must send the code for arabic priniting First,
So Your Code must be like this:

```
byte[] arabicFont = new byte[]{0x1b, 0x77, 0x46};
mLinePrinter.write(arabicFont);
Arabic864 arabic864 = new Arabic864();
byte[] arabicTXT = arabic864.Convert("بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم", false);
mLinePrinter.write(arabicTXT);
mLinePrinter.newLine(1);
```